# How to add new EditText below an object and move the button below it?

Tags: android, android-layout, button, android-edittext

I have an EditText and a button, it will look like this

[image: edittext1]

I want the button to create an EditText below EditText 1 and the button will automatically moved below the new added EditText, so it will look like this

[image: edittext2]

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of ways you can do this but the easiest is to put in a Linear Layout with orientation Vertical. Using a Constraint Layout as your parent layout, constrain the linear layout between the EditText1 and the Button. Then when you tap the button just insert the new EditText into that layout and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the maximum number of the `EditText` that the user can add you need to define witch approach use.

(1) One way is to do a container, for example, a `LinearLayout`, and use [addView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup#addView(android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)) to add the `EditText` as a child when the user clicks the button. But this a simple approach for a small number of children.

(2) Another way is using a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview). This is better for large number of children.

There are other ways to do, depending on how complex this `EditText` will, even for a small number of elements (2) can be good.